# Oracle Variable Scope

Tags: oracle, plsql, scope, oracle12c

I'm fairly new to Oracle, but have had a good search.  Can someone explain the scoping rules in relation to this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        Variable1 number := 1;

    BEGIN
       DECLARE 
        Variable2 number := 2;


        BEGIN  
            dbms_output.put_line('Variable1: ' || Variable1); 
            dbms_output.put_line('Variable2: ' || Variable2); 
        END;

        BEGIN  
            dbms_output.put_line('Variable1: ' || Variable1); 
            dbms_output.put_line('Variable2: ' || Variable2); 
        END;
    END;
END;
```

errors with:

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 17, column 55: PLS-00201: identifier
>   'VARIABLE2' must be declared ORA-06550: line 17, column 17: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Why is Variable2 unavailable in my second attempt to output it?  Is there a way to achieve access to Variable2 within the second BEGIN...END block, or is this just the way Oracle works?

I'm using Oracle 12c. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your indentation is fooling you:
A block is (the DECLARE part is optional)

```
DECLARE
   ...
BEGIN
   ...
END
```

and the second output is clearly after the block in which Variable2 is declared.

Comment: Thanks, @Turo, that explains it perfectly...essentially swapping the declares to approve the appropriate begins, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A PL/SQL block has the format:

```
DECLARE
  -- your variables
BEGIN
  -- your statements
END;
```

The `DECLARE` part of the block is optional (but is still part of the block)

So your code is:

```
BEGIN                         -- Block 1 Start
  DECLARE                     -- Block 1.1 Start
    Variable1 number := 1;
  BEGIN
    DECLARE                   -- Block 1.1.1 Start
      Variable2 number := 2;
    BEGIN  
      NULL;
    END;                      -- Block 1.1.1 End

    BEGIN                     -- Block 1.1.2 Start
      NULL;
    END;                      -- Block 1.1.2 End
  END;                        -- Block 1.1 End
END;                          -- Block 1 End
```

You have 4 PL/SQL blocks:

- Block 1 has no local variables.
- Block 1.1 is nested inside Block 1 and declares the local variable `variable1`
- Block 1.1.1 is nested inside Block 1.1 (which is nested inside Block 1) and declares the variable `variable2` and can access its surrounding block's scopes so can see `variable1`.
- Block 1.1.2 is nested inside Block 1.1 (which is nested inside Block 1) and has no local variables but can access its access its surrounding block's scopes so can see `variable1`. `variable2` is not in an ancestor's scope but is in a sibling and is not visible.